# Regex to validate filename

Tags: c#, regex, .net-2.0

If filename has another characters then this `a-zA-Z0-9!@$%^&*()_+=-[]{}';,.`
we must replace them in some character or delete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9!@$%^&*()_+=[\]{}';,.-]", "X");
```

should do it.

Explanation: I copied your list of characters and pasted them into a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) (`[^...]`). I just had to make two minor modifications: Escaping the closing bracket (`\]`) and putting the dash at the end of the string.

Answer (score 5):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

string path = ...;

IEnumerable<char> invalidChars = Enumerable.Concat(
    Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars(),
    Path.GetInvalidPathChars());

foreach (char c in invalidChars)
{
    path = path.Replace(c, ''); // or any char you want
}
```

Comment: +1 for specifying Path.GetInvalid[FileName|Path]Chars()